# NOAUTH Authentication required redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redis, redis-cache, redis-server

Start **redis-server**:

> redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf

Redis config file (**/usr/local/etc/redis.conf**):

```
... 
requirepass 'foobared'
...
```

Rails - **application.yml**:

```
...
development:
  redis_password: 'foobared
...
```

**The Error**:

```
Redis::CommandError - NOAUTH Authentication required.:
...
app/models/user.rb:54:in `last_accessed_at' 
...
```

**app/models/user.rb:54**:

```
Line 53 - def last_accessed_at
Line 54 -  Rails.cache.read(session_key)
Line 55 - end
```

and **session_key** is just an attribute of **User** model.

BTW:

```
± ps -ef | grep redis
  501 62491 57789   0  1:45PM ttys001    0:00.37 redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
  501 62572 59388   0  1:54PM ttys002    0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn redis
```

Comment: did you forget show us where you set password something like this ```Redis.new(:password => "mysecret")``` or did you set this password somewhere in rails app?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error:

I just commented out the ***requirepass*** line.

```
# requirepass 'foobared'
```

It worked in my case.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30195296)